# Querying Google Big Query Using .Net API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-bigquery

I am trying to read data from Google big query using c#. I have installed nuget package..when It reaches the stage to execute query it throws an exception that user does not have permission to run query on project following is the code sample I am using..

```
public class BQObject
{
    private static Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.BigqueryService returnService()
    {
        FileStream stream;
        UserCredential credential;

        using (stream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery },
                "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
        }

        var Service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            //ApplicationName = "BigQueryDemoApp"
        });

        return Service;
    }

    public DataTable returnDT(string queryParam)
    {
        Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.BigqueryService localService = returnService();
        JobsResource j = localService.Jobs;
        QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();
        qr.Query = queryParam;

        //at this point, it throws an exception

        QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, "Project ID").Execute();

        //process response
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the extra bits of code from your sample to narrow it down to where the exception occurs. Is that correct? It might be helpful to provide the exact message/type from the exception.

Comment: Make sure the user you are running the job as is a member of the project in which you are running the job.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon thanks for suggestion.. can you please explain it a bit more... How can I do that as I have been provided with Client_Secret.Json   file and project Id by the service provider